# Page redirect only from specific page

Tags: javascript, redirect

I am trying to redirect from a splash page to another. I have this code but I want it to be activated only from the first page the users arrive (the homepage) and not from every page on the site.

This is the code I am using but it keeps on launching on every page:

```
var url ='http://cargocollective.com/clairelefevre/about';
var delay = 6;
var d = delay * 1000;
window.setTimeout ('parent.location.replace(url)', d);
```

Thanks,
Matan

Comment: So just put the code only on that one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the `parent.location` value:

```
if(parent.location == 'http://cargocollective.com/')
{
   var url ='http://cargocollective.com/clairelefevre/about';
   var delay = 6;
   var d = delay * 1000;
   window.setTimeout ('parent.location.replace(url)', d);
}
```

But honestly, it's not very clean IMO. What I would do is put a hidden input in your homepage, with a id and value. Test if the user is on the homepage by testing this input.

You can also check the `location.pathname` value.

```
if(parent.location.pathname == '/')
{
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referer, so:

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.origin) == -1) {
    window.setTimeout ('parent.location.replace(url)', d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname;
var homeUrl = "http://cargocollective.com/";
if (currUrl == homeUrl) {
    var url ='http://cargocollective.com/clairelefevre/about';
    var delay = 6;
    var d = delay * 1000;
    window.setTimeout ('parent.location.replace(url)', d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of solving this problem come to mind.

1. Only place the code on the home page inside a script tag:

   `<script>`

   ```
   var url ='http://cargocollective.com/clairelefevre/about';
   var delay = 6;
   window.setTimeout ('parent.location.replace(url)', delay * 1000);
   ```

   `</script>`
2. Test the location of the page is correct with an if statement before redirecting

   ```
   if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
       var url ='http://cargocollective.com/clairelefevre/about';
       var delay = 6;
       window.setTimeout ('parent.location.replace(url)', d * 1000);
   }
   ```